# How to add up checkbox calculations

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to get this work. I have 6 checkboxes with the different prices on each of them. Whenever the user clicks on a checkbox the price is shown up in the total box, if user click on another checkbox the price will go up again and so on and so forth. I would be grateful if you could spot something I can't see.

## HTML

```html
    <form id="bookingForm">
    <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='6' data-price='18.50'></span>
    <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='17' data-price='0.00'></span>
    <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='14' data-price='13.00'></span>
    <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='11' data-price='35.00'></span>
    <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='9' data-price='16.00'></span>

    <section id="checkCost">
            <h2>Total cost</h2>
            Total <input type="text" name="total" size="10" readonly>
        </section>
    </form>
```

## Javascript

```js
 const l_form = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
 const l_total = l_form.getElementById('total')
 const t_checkboxes = l_form.querySelectorAll('input[data-price][type=checkbox]');
 const t_cbCount = t_checkboxes.length;

 let t_totalPrice = 0;

 for (let t_i=0; t_i< t_cbCount; t_i++) {
      const t_box = t_checkboxes[t_i];

     if (t_box.checked) {
        t_totalPrice += t_box.dataset.price;
     }
 };

 l_value = t_totalPrice;
```

Comment: Your input has no ID, it has a name, and `l_value` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere before you're trying to set it to something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to listen to whenever the checkbox gets checked, you can accomplish this using the 'change' event.

```js
const checkBoxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="event[]"]'));
checkBoxes.forEach(x => x.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal));

function calculateTotal(event) {
 const totalPrice = checkBoxes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.checked) {
   acc += parseFloat(curr.getAttribute('data-price'), 10);
  }
 
  return acc;
 }, 0);
 
 console.log('Total price ', totalPrice);
}
```

```html
<span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='6' data-price='18.50'></span>
<span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='17' data-price='0.00'></span>
<span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='14' data-price='13.00'></span>
<span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='11' data-price='35.00'></span>
<span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='9' data-price='16.00'></span>
```